# Using 'sorted' function for words gives an output with letters being split and sorted

Tags: python-2.7, sorting

I'm new to python (2.7) and stackoverflow. I'm trying to learn how to use the 'sorted' function. When I use the 'sorted' function, the sentence splits into individual letters and sorts those letters in ascending order. But that is not what I want. I want to sort my words in ascending order. I'm trying to run this code

```
peace = "This is one of the most useful sentences in the whole wide world."

def pinkan (one):
    return sorted (one)

print pinkan (peace)
```

But the output I get is something of this sort:

```
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'T', 'c', 'd', 
'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'f'
, 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'n', 'n', 
'n', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'r', 's', 's', 's', 's', 's
', 's', 't', 't', 't', 't', 'u', 'u', 'w', 'w', 'w']
```

I would appreciate any help/suggestion. Thanks :-)

Comment: Have you tried to google it like "python sort words" ?

Comment: I did, but didn’t come across anyone who had asked similar question as me :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using first `split()` to generate a list of words, then `sort()`, to sort that list alphabetically in ascending order:

```
peace = "This is one of the most useful sentences in the whole wide world."
terms = peace.split()
terms.sort(key=str.lower)
output = " ".join(terms)
print(output)

['in', 'is', 'most', 'of', 'one', 'sentences', 'the', 'the', 'This', 'useful',
    'whole', 'wide', 'world.']
```

Comment: The sorting can be done case-insensitively by using `str.lower` as a key function: `terms.sort(key=str.lower)`

Comment: How do I do it if I want to use it in a module?

Comment: @princebanana The logic I used should not really need to change AFAIK.